# Dedicated OJDBC connections in Docker & Kubernetes

Tags: java, multithreading, kubernetes, ojdbc

I am running simple native Java 8 code to spawn number of threads. These threads connect to database through their own dedicated OJDBC connection. As Database is continuously populated with records so thee threads use this dedicated connection to perform various tasks in database. each thread poll database after sometime to fetch records then process it and then re poll database. the connection remains same for lifetime of thread.
This whole setup works fine if i run it on simple VM. There are no connection closures but as soon as i moved this java code to Kubernetes problems start arising .
After few times each thread start throwing following exception

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3694)
```

There is no re initiation of JDBC connection because threads assume that connection is dedicated and our backend system does not close the connection.
This connection closure only happen in Kubernetes and at random so i am curious is there any specific network settings i need to do to make dedicated connections work in Kubernetes ?

Comment: Do you send TCP keepalives (or protocol level keepalives)? If you're connecting through the kube-proxy mesh you might be hitting iptables timeouts due to inactivity.

Comment: no there is no keep alive sent by threads so i assume you are right that iptables trigger timeout. How can i set unlimited timeouts for all outgoing connections from pods ?

Answer (score 1):

Echoing down from comments, you probably want to turn on TCP keepalives but if that's impossible look at the `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established` sysctl and similar conntrack settings. You can also potentially bypass the proxy mesh using a headless-mode Service instead though that would likely impact your failover process so be sure to check that carefully.

Comment: Thanks for ponting it out 
I checked stetings and currently its set to `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 86400`
So its 24 hours 

One more thing when this problem happens i see lots of connection in TIME_WAIT state in conntrack list 

So you are suggesting to lower that time ?